# Impact analysis of individual independent components

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, anova, optimization, multivariate-analysis

I need help in understanding how we can analyse the impact of an individual independent variable (campaign media type in this case) on a dependent variable (sales performance here) when not using the traditional A/B testing approach. The media #2 will be rolled out to all customers without any control group. What I think makes things complicated is that we have other campaigns running which have an impact on the sales. Nothing is going to change for Media #1 & Media #3 but is there a way we can say with confidence that this revision of campaign for media #2 helped us by x% etc. in uplift in sales. The data will be something like this:

| Date | Media #1 traffic | Media #2 traffic(the one being updated) | Media #3 traffic | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 10234 | 2245 | 9008 | 345 |
| 2 Jan | 9875 | 2387 | 8657 | 332 |
| 3 Jan | 9456 | 2198 | 8702 | 399 |
| 4 Jan | 11043 | 2167 | 9123 | 389 |
| 5 Jan | 9901 | 2278 | 8900 | 334 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 25 Jan | 10034 | 2290 | 8560 | 356 |
| **26 Jan (Media #2 revision date)** | 9922 | **2987** | 8790 | 399 |
| 27 Jan | 9809 | 3003 | 9005 | 432 |
| 28 Jan | 10432 | 3100 | 9023 | 401 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... | 408 |
| 10 Feb | 10346 | 3103 | 8690 | 423 |
| 11 Feb | 9987 | 2967 | 8976 | 412 |
| 12 Feb | 9678 | 3001 | 9110 | 424 |
| 13 Feb | 10768 | 3009 | 8998 | 434 |

P.S. : From the simplistic Pre/Post analysis we can say that new media helped us in increasing traffic from media #2 (as shown in table) and we see that avg daily sales increased by a% [in post period], avg media #1 traffic changed by b% [in post period],avg media #2 traffic increased by c% [in post period] and avg media #3 traffic changed by d% [in post period]. Is there a way (method or metric) to attribute what portion of that a% increase in sale is being driven by the c% increase in media #2 traffic?